# how to modal form select option selected json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

here I want to select option selected 
(to select the results in selected)
my modal form select:

```
<select id="doctor2" name="doctor2">
  <? foreach($staff as $doctor){?>
  <option value="<?=$doctor['staff_id']?>"><?=$doctor['name']?></option>
<?}?> 
</select>
```

how to ajax json data response select option selected:

```
$('.tg-invoices').on('click', '.item-edit', function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('data-id1');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'get',
    url: '<?=base_url()?>Clinic/editAppointment',
    data: {id: id},
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

  $("#doctor2 option[value="+data.doctor+"]").attr("selected","selected");

    },
    error: function(){
      alert('Could not Edit Data edit');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: where is class `tg-invoices` exist in html

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. Can you explain your requirement. Also please provide all relevant code, a fiddle if possible.

Comment: Please make your question simple and easier to understand your requirement.